# Windows 10 shows "Other Devices(1) - Roku" but I do not own this device?

Tags: windows-10

I am seeing a mysterious device listed in Other Device of my Windows 10 PC. I do not know when this started occurring but I notice a Roku device that appears periodically then vanishes after a few minutes:

[image]

I do not own any Roku devices and I have never installed any Roku software or hardware on my PC before.

From searching I can find no reference to unknown Roku device, or how to remove Roku from Other Devices in Windows.

I did however read that Roku is capable of screen mirroring or some other intrusive behavior so I just want to remove it completely from my PC or understand why I am seeing it listed.

My PC does not have Wifi and the Bluetooth is disabled, I have checked my WRT3200ACN router and can see no unusual devices listed in the network map.

I have typed Roku into Add or Remove Programs but nothing is listed.
I have searched Device Manager but can't find any Roku devices there.

Could someone please help me determine what this device is or recommend a way to remove or block it from my PC?

Comment: You are looking at the network view thus the device you are searching is in your local network not on or in your PC. Roku seems to be the name of some TV - this is where you should start searching in your network.

Comment: You can disable device discovery if you dislike your machine discovering devices on your network.  There is a good chance, it was on a network your device was connected to, I mention that because the device doesn’t have an IP address.  Verify if you have a television with Roku capability.

Comment: I don't understand how there is a Roku TV on my network, I do not own a TV much less any Roku TVs. Also I just unplugged all cables except for my main PC connected directly to my Router. I have also changed all Wifi passwords on my router. I am very worried about this persistent device. How else can I determine what it is or if it is harmful?

Comment: After some research I noticed WPS was enabled on my router. After disabling this feature I no longer see rogue devices on any of my PCs